# make sure that punctuation is always placed in the right way

Tags: regex

The following characters: .?!,… (maybe more, open for suggestions), should always be outputted directly after a word, and always with a space after it.

correct:

```
This is a fox. It is Brown.
```

Wrong:

```
This is a fox . It is Brown.
This is a fox.It is Brown
This is a fox .It is Brown.
```

I basically want any punctuation. except this:

```
[^\s][\.?!,…][\s]
```

Comment: What's your regex flavor? Are you looking for a substitution or just match?

Comment: javascript, and a i'll substitue it with ". " or whatever the punctuation is. But that part is not very important.

Answer (score 2):

You might use lookarounds if supported to assert what is on the left is not a whitespace char and what is on the right is not a non whitespace char

```
(?<!\s)[.?!,…](?!\S)
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/tgZoRI/1)

Edit

If you want to match the opposite and replace with a dot and space, you might use an alternation with 2 capturing groups and a callback function.

```
\s+([.?!,…])\s*|([^\s.?!,…][.?!,…])(?!\s)
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/6z6f6I/1)

```js
const regex = /\s+([.?!,…])\s*|([^\s.?!,…][.?!,…])(?!\s)/g;
let str = `This is a fox. It is Brown.

This is a fox . It is Brown.
This is a fox.It is Brown
This is a fox .It is Brown.
`;

str = str.replace(regex, function(_, g1, g2) {
  return (g1 || g2) + " ";
});
console.log(str);
```

Comment: I want to match the exact opposite punctuations from those ^^

Comment: Basically what I'm looking for is not a whitespace before OR a whitespace after, this also seems to be an AND.

Comment: @Himmators This will match not a whitespace before or after https://regex101.com/r/aEGYJJ/1

Answer (score 0):

this is one way

```
print(re.search(r'.*(\.)(\s).*',str1).group())
```

Comment: please try out this  print(re.search(r'.*\w(\.)(\s).*',str1).group())